# 2D Infinitely looping Array of elements

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, logic

**The Goal :**

The idea is to create an element grid (image gallery for exemple) that would infinitely loop on itself scrolling on two axes.
There should be no holes nor too much randomness (avoid having the same element randomly falling aside from itself). And this no matter how many element there is in the first place (it seems easy to infinite loop through a grid of 16 (4*4) elements, not that much over 17 (17*1). (My guess is that any prime number of elements is by definition a pain to make a grid of).

So I actually found a wonderful working exemple :
http://www.benstockley.com/

It's actually really close (probably better) than what I was imagining. Now it's using canvas and i tried looking at the javascript and it's a 30000 minified lines long script so I really can't read any core logic behind it.

---

---

**Math side / Problem solving :**

This is the logic and theory behind the problem, the math involved and the mindset.
How the program should process the list of elements so we have no holes, infinite grid, best repartion of the elements over all the axes.

My guess is that it somehow has to be procedural. I'm not sure if we should create grids or loop through the list on every axes (kind of like sudoku ? i don't know);

---

---

**Pratical side / UI / UX :**

Any advice on the technologies involved, pieces of code. I'm guessing it classic DOM is out of the way and that somehow canvas or 2D webgl will be mandatory. But I would love to hear any advice on this side.

Besides all the elements grid processing. The UI and UX involved in exploring a 2D infinite or vast layout in DOM or renderer is somehow not classical. The best technologies or advice on doing this are welcome.

---

---

**Exemples :**

I would welcome any working exemple that somewhat share an aspect of this problem.

Comment: Do you imagine the list of elements getting really large?

Comment: It could be yes. In my direct usecase it wouldn't go over 40 elements or so. But thinking about a way to handle a somehow large list of elements (maybe to a hundred or more) could be very interesting as it could have many applications. Maybe we don't even know the hole list (client side) when we start panning & zooming. So both smallish and potentialy infinite (procedural ?) organisation of the content would be interesting to me.

Comment: Based on the benstockley.com I think I managed identify a formula that could able me to find which element to put in which coordinates. See if i go down by one row (Y+1) and go six times to the left (X-6) I always find the same image. So i'm guessing the formula is : `AbsoluteIndex = Xn - (6Yn)` and then `AbsoluteIndex %(modulo) SumOfElements = ElementIndex`

While this is interesting I do believe it's not ideal as if we have 300 element, the index shift between Y lines should be higher than 6. Should we determine this based on total number or elements, or total number of visible elements ?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnv6mumd/) that's set up to arrange your 2d grid.

It functions by using horizontal and vertical "step sizes". So, moving one step right in the grid advances the horizontal step size in the list. Moving one step down advances the vertical step size in the list (and they accumulate).

We allow the advances in the list to loop back to zero when the end is reached.

It likely makes sense to use a horizontal step size of 1 (so a row of your grid will maintain your list order). For the vertical step size, you want an integer that shares no common divisors with the list length. Though it's no guarantee, I used the (rounded) square root of the list length as something that will work in lots of cases.

I'll reproduce the fiddle here:

```js
var list = ['red','green','blue','cyan','orange','yellow','pink'];

var hstep = 1;
var vstep = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(list.length));

function getListItem(x,y) {
 var index = x * hstep + y * vstep;
  return list[index % list.length];
}

var elementSize = 30;
var gutterSize = 10;

function getOffset(x,y) {
  return [10 + (elementSize + gutterSize) * x, 10 + (elementSize + gutterSize) * y];
}

var frame = $('.frame');

function drawElement(x,y) {
 var listItem = getListItem(x,y);
  var offsets = getOffset(x,y);
  var element = $('<div></div>').addClass('element').css({
   left: offsets[0] + 'px',
    top: offsets[1] + 'px',
    'background-color': listItem
  });
  frame.append(element);
}

function drawElements() {
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  while (10 + (elementSize + gutterSize) * x < frame.width()) {
    while (10 + (elementSize + gutterSize) * y < frame.height()) {
     drawElement(x,y);
      y++;
    }
    y = 0;
    x++;
  }
}

drawElements();
```

```css
.frame {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame .element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button.up {top: 0px; left: 46%;}
button.down {top: 355px; left: 46%;}
button.left {top: 160px; left: 15px;}
button.right {top: 160px; right: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="frame">

</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="up">&uarr;</button>
  <button class="down">&darr;</button>
  <button class="left">&larr;</button>
  <button class="right">&rarr;</button>
</div>
```

---

You can see I've left some simple buttons to implement movement, but they are not functional yet. If you wanted to continue implementation along the lines of what I've done here, you could render your elements to a certain range beyond the visible frame, then implement some sort of animated repositioning. The `renderElements` function here only renders what is visible, so you can use something like that and not get stuck in rendering infinite elements, even though there's no theoretical limit to how far you can "scroll".

Comment: This is amazing. I figured the logic yesterday and though the same about using rounded square root of list length for Y shift ! I was just  playing with PixiJS and I kinda was struggling with implementation and thought "let's see this stackoverflow posted yesterday". And there it is. Amazing.  I will need to play around of course and if i manage to pull this out will update this stack. Thanks a lot (my +1 doesn't show up yet as i'm a newbie, but it's there)

Comment: It's kind of an awesome problem! Implementing movement I can see two ways to go ahead: one would be maintain some variables as "virtual" left and top scrolls, and update the absolute positions of the elements to account. The other might be to add an intermediate `div` between the frame and the elements... have the elements positioned within the intermediate, and the intermediate's position within the frame could represent user scrolling.

Comment: I actually went with both aha ! This is usefull because i wan't to be able to move the origin pixel by pixel but update the grid "cell" by "cell"

Answer (score 1):

@arbuthnott I edited your code to implement the exploration via decrementing relativeX and relativeY variables. Also I inserted an "origin" div (1x1 px, overflow visible). This DOM element will represent the X and Y origin. I'm not sure it's essential but it's really convenient.

Now my function currently remove all elements and reinsert all elements on each update (every 500ms for now).

The idear would be to find a way to compare which elements I need versus which one already exists.
Maybe storing existing elements into an array, and compare the array with the "query" array. Than see just the elements that are missing.

This is the idear, not sure about the implementation (I suck at handling arrays).

https://jsfiddle.net/bnv6mumd/64/

```js
var sources = ['red','green','blue','cyan','orange','yellow','pink','purple'];

var frame = $('.frame'),
  origin = $('.origin');

var fWidth = 600,
  fHeight = 300,
    srcTotal = sources.length,
    srcSquare = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(srcTotal)),
    rX = 0,
    rY = 0;

var gridSize = 30,
  gutterSize = 5,
  elementSize = gridSize - gutterSize;


function getSourceItem(x,y) {
 var index = x + y * srcSquare;
  return sources[Math.abs(index) % srcTotal];
}

function getOffset(x,y) {
  return [gridSize * x,gridSize * y];
}

function drawElement(x,y) {
 var sourceItem = getSourceItem(x,y);
  var offsets = getOffset(x,y);
  var element = $('<div></div>').addClass('element').css({
   left: offsets[0] + 'px',
    top: offsets[1] + 'px',
    'background-color': sourceItem,
  });
  origin.append(element);
}

function init() {
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  while ( gridSize * x < fWidth) {
    while ( gridSize * y < fHeight) {
     drawElement(x,y);
      y++;
    }
    y = 0;
    x++;
  }
}

function updateElements() {
 origin.empty();
  var x = -Math.trunc(rX / gridSize) -1, y = - Math.trunc(rY / gridSize) -1;
  while ( gridSize * x + rX < fWidth) {
    while ( gridSize * y + rY < fHeight) {
     drawElement(x,y);
      y++;
    }
    y = -Math.ceil(rY / gridSize);
    x++;
  }
}

function animate() {
  rX -= 5;
  rY -= 5;
  origin.css({left: rX, top: rY})
  updateElements();
  console.log("relative X : " + rX + " | relative Y : " + rY);
}

setInterval(animate, 500)
init();
```

```css
.frame {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.origin {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
}

.frame .element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">
<div class="origin" style="top:0;left:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also this version ables to see how blocs appear and disapear. I'm not sure why there is this pattern but it's not that bad
https://jsfiddle.net/bnv6mumd/65/

Comment: I like that fiddle version. Only creating the elements you need! I think you could adapt that without too much trouble to listen for drag events or button clicks instead of the automated animate. But looks really nice!

Comment: Yes but i regenerate ALL element every frame. Wouldn't it be better to delete old ones and create new one only ? Not sure how yet

Answer (score 0):

This is my final snippet version (i will start to work on real implementation specific to my case now).

I think I optimized in a decent way DOM operations, code structure etc (I am very well open to suggestions though).

I now only update the elements that needs to be updated (click near the frame to show overflow)

https://jsfiddle.net/bnv6mumd/81/

```js
var sources = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'orange', 'yellow', 'pink', 'purple'];

var frame = $('.frame'),
    origin = $('.origin');

var srcTotal = sources.length,
    srcSquare = Math.round(Math.sqrt(srcTotal)),
    fWidth = 200,
    fHeight = 200,
    cellSize = 50,
    gutterSize = 20,
    gridSize = [Math.floor(fWidth / cellSize) + 1, Math.floor(fHeight / cellSize) + 1],
    aX = 0, // Absolute/Applied Coordinates
    aY = 0,
    rX = 0, // Relative/frame Coordinates
    rY = 0;

function getSrcItem(x, y) {
    var index = x + y * srcSquare;
    return sources[Math.abs(index) % srcTotal];
}

function getOffset(x, y) {
    return [cellSize * x, cellSize * y];
}

function getY() {
    return Math.floor(-rY / cellSize);
}

function getX() {
    return Math.floor(-rX / cellSize);
}

function drawElement(x, y) {
    var srcItem = getSrcItem(x, y),
        offsets = getOffset(x, y),
        element = $('<div></div>').addClass('element').css({
            left: offsets[0] + 'px',
            top: offsets[1] + 'px',
            'background-color': srcItem,
        }).attr({
            "X": x,
            "Y": y
        });
    origin.append(element);
}

function drawCol(x, y) {
    var maxY = y + gridSize[1];
    while (y <= maxY + 1) {
        drawElement(x - 1, y - 1);
        y++;
    }
}

function drawLign(x, y) {
    var maxX = x + gridSize[0];
    while (x <= maxX + 1) {
        drawElement(x - 1, y - 1);
        x++;
    }
}

function drawGrid() {
    origin.empty();
    var x = getX(),
        y = getY(),
        maxX = x + gridSize[0],
        maxY = y + gridSize[1];
    while (y <= maxY + 1) {
        drawLign(x, y);
        x = getX();
        y++;
    }
}

function updateX(x, y, diffX, diffY) {
    if (Math.sign(diffX) == -1) {
        drawCol(aX - 1, y);
        $('[x=' + (aX + gridSize[0]) + ']').remove();
        aX--;
    } else if (Math.sign(diffY) == 1) {
        drawCol(aX + gridSize[0] + 2, y);
        $('[x=' + (aX - 1) + ']').remove();
        aX++;
    }
}

function updateY(x, y, diffX, diffY) {
    if (Math.sign(diffY) == -1) {
        drawLign(x, aY - 1);
        $('[y=' + (aY + gridSize[0]) + ']').remove();
        aY--;
    } else if (Math.sign(diffY) == 1) {
        drawLign(x, aY + gridSize[0] + 2);
        $('[y=' + (aY - 1) + ']').remove();
        aY++;
    }
}

function animate() {
    rX += 1;
    rY += 1;
    origin.css({
        left: rX,
        top: rY
    });
    var x = getX(),
        y = getY(),
        diffX = x - aX,
        diffY = y - aY;
    if (diffX) {
        updateX(x, y, diffX, diffY)
    };
    if (diffY) {
        updateY(x, y, diffX, diffY)
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

$('body').click(function() {
$(frame).toggleClass("overflow");
})
drawGrid();
animate();
```

```css
.frame {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.overflow{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.origin {
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
}

.frame .element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame overflow">
    <div class="origin" style="top:0;left:0;"></div>
</div>
```